# Implementar Traductor Lenguaje de Programacion (Análisis Léxico, Sintactico)

Tags: vb.net, compilador

Como parte de un trabajo de Compiladores, debo programar un editor de texto que reciba como entrada el lenguaje Visual Basic y lo transforme a otro lenguaje a mi eleccion. Actualmente estoy utilizando Visual Basic para programar lo anterior.

[image: EditorTexto]

Lo primero que hice fue recibir la cadena de entrada y separarla en tokens, clasificandolos en palabras reservadas, variables, simbolos de agrupacion y operadores.

```
Public Sub Procesar(Cadena As String, lstResultado As ListView, lstSimbolos As ListView)
        Try
            Dim cadenaAux As String = ""
            Dim cadenaSimbolos As String = ""
            ' Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) se agrega este tipo de propiedad para saber cuando hay un salto de linea 
            Cadena &= Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10) & "!" 'bandera que indica si es final de texto
            Dim contador As Integer = 0

            While (Cadena.Chars(contador) <> "!")
                'verifica que exista un salto de linea para insertar token a la lista, tambien verifica que este vacio la cadena aux
                'en el textbox si funcion ay detecta la libreriade microsoft visual para el chrw13 que es la tecla intro pero en richtextbox no funciona
                'detexta al final de la cadena el chrw(13) porque se le concatena a la cadena que se evualua, de lo contrario no lo detectara. 
                If (Cadena.Chars(contador) = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)) AndAlso cadenaAux.Trim <> "" Then

                    Dim palabras As String() = cadenaAux.TrimStart.Split(",")
                    cadenaAux = ""
                    cadenaSimbolos = ""
                    For x As Integer = 0 To palabras.Count - 1
                        If Comparador(palabras(x), Propiedad) Then
                            cadenaAux &= " (RESERVADO) " & palabras(x)
                        ElseIf Comparador(palabras(x), Operador) Then
                            cadenaSimbolos &= " (OPERADOR) " & palabras(x)
                        ElseIf Comparador(palabras(x), Delimitador) Then
                            cadenaSimbolos &= " (DELIMITADOR) " & palabras(x)
                        ElseIf EsNumero(palabras(x)) Then
                            cadenaAux &= " (NUMERO) " & palabras(x)
                        Else
                            cadenaAux &= " (PALABRA) " & palabras(x)
                        End If
                    Next

                    Dim lst As New ListViewItem(cadenaAux)
                    lstResultado.Items.Add(lst)
                    lst = New ListViewItem(cadenaSimbolos)
                    lstSimbolos.Items.Add(lst)
                    cadenaAux = ""
                    cadenaSimbolos = ""
                End If

                'se reemplaza proceso anterior por funcion que verifica y valida el doble o triple o multiple espacios 
                cadenaAux &= GetToken(Cadena.Chars(contador))

                contador += 1
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Metodo para evaluar tokens:

```
'evalua la lista de token obtenidas del proceso que analiza todo el texto
    Public Sub Evalua(lstResultado As ListView, lstPropiedad As ListView, lstOperador As ListView, lstIdentificador As ListView, lstNumero As ListView, lstError As ListView)
        Try
            Dim CadenaAux As String = ""
            Dim Palabra As String = ""
            Dim contador As Integer = 0

            For x As Integer = 0 To lstResultado.Items.Count - 1

                Dim item As ListViewItem = lstResultado.Items(x)
                CadenaAux = item.SubItems(0).Text
                CadenaAux &= ",!" 'se coloca la coma antes del fin de cadena para saber que el caracter a continuacion es el fin de cadena

                'algoritmo que compara las palabras encontradas para saber en que lista insertarlas
                While CadenaAux.Chars(contador) <> "!"
                    If (CadenaAux.Chars(contador) = ",") Then
                        If Comparador(Palabra, Operador) Then
                            Dim lst As New ListViewItem(Palabra)
                            lstOperador.Items.Add(lst)
                        ElseIf Comparador(Palabra, Propiedad) Then
                            Dim lst As New ListViewItem(Palabra)
                            lstPropiedad.Items.Add(lst)
                        Else
                            'si no encuentra la palabra en las listas creadas, las evalua para saber si son identificadores o numeros. 

                            'Verifica si el primer caracter es numero con el algoritmo dado en clase si no lo manda al otro analizador de caracteres.
                            If EsNumero(Palabra.Chars(0)) Then
                                MsgBox(Palabra & "Numero ")
                                AnalizadorNumerico(Palabra, lstNumero, lstError) ' por automata
                            Else
                                MsgBox(Palabra & "Palabra ")
                                Analizador(Palabra, lstIdentificador, lstNumero, lstError)
                            End If

                        End If
                        Palabra = ""
                    Else
                        Palabra &= CadenaAux.Chars(contador)
                    End If
                    contador += 1
                End While

                'Reinicio de las variables auxiliares
                contador = 0
                Palabra = ""
                CadenaAux = ""
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Automata para evaluar si token es numero:

```
Private Sub AnalizadorNumerico(Palabra As String, lstNumero As ListView, lstError As ListView)
        Dim Estado As Integer = 1
        Dim contador As Integer = 0
        Dim Analizado As Boolean = True
        Dim PalabraAux As String = Palabra & "!"

        'algoritmo de analizador lexico 
        While PalabraAux.Chars(contador) <> "!"
            Select Case Estado
                Case 1
                    If EsNumero(PalabraAux.Chars(contador)) Then
                        Estado = 2
                    Else
                        Analizado = False
                    End If
                Case 2
                    If EsNumero(PalabraAux.Chars(contador)) Then
                        Estado = 2
                    ElseIf PalabraAux.Chars(contador) = "." Then
                        Estado = 3
                    ElseIf PalabraAux.Chars(contador) = "E" Then
                        Estado = 5
                    Else
                        Analizado = False
                    End If
                Case 3
                    If EsNumero(PalabraAux.Chars(contador)) Then
                        Estado = 4
                        Analizado = True
                    Else
                        Analizado = False
                    End If
                Case 4
                    If EsNumero(PalabraAux.Chars(contador)) Then
                        Estado = 4
                        Analizado = True
                    ElseIf PalabraAux.Chars(contador) = "E" Then
                        Estado = 5
                    Else
                        Analizado = False
                    End If
                Case 5
                    If EsNumero(PalabraAux.Chars(contador)) Then
                        Estado = 7
                        Analizado = True
                    ElseIf PalabraAux.Chars(contador) = "-" Then
                        Estado = 6
                    ElseIf PalabraAux.Chars(contador) = "+" Then
                        Estado = 6
                    Else
                        Analizado = False
                    End If
                Case 6
                    If EsNumero(PalabraAux.Chars(contador)) Then
                        Estado = 7
                        Analizado = True
                    Else
                        Analizado = False
                    End If
                Case 7
                    If EsNumero(PalabraAux.Chars(contador)) Then
                        Estado = 7
                        Analizado = True
                    End If

            End Select
            contador += 1
        End While

        'evaluacion de la palabra encontrada 
        'e inserta en su lista respectiva
        'If (Estado = 4 Or Estado = 7 Or Estado = 2) And Analizado Then
        If (Estado = 4 Or Estado = 7 Or Estado = 2) And Analizado Then
            Dim lst As New ListViewItem(Palabra)
            lstNumero.Items.Add(lst)
        ElseIf Not Analizado Then
            Dim lst As New ListViewItem(Palabra)
            lstError.Items.Add(lst)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Los tokens despues de ser evaluados por automatas los almaceno en ListViews, que despues muestro en una ventana.

```
Private Sub MnuResultado_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles MnuResultado.ItemClick
        Try
            Dim frm As New FrmAnalizadorLexico
            For Each item In lstReservadas.Items
                frm.lstDatos.Items.Add(item.Text)
            Next
            For Each item In lstSimbolos.Items
                frm.lstSimbolos.Items.Add(item.Text)
            Next
            frm.ShowDialog()
            frm = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            cls.MensajeError(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image: Tokens]

Para este traductor no debo hacer validaciones de signos de agrupación, que verifiquen si faltan paréntesis o llaves. Solamente transformar los tokens obtenidos a otro lenguaje. El lenguaje final puede ser cualquiera.

Asimismo no es todo el lenguaje el que debo convertir, solo la estructura de un For, While e If.

Por ejemplo si tengo:

```
For i = 1 To i <= 5

Next
```

Debo convertirlo a :

```
for(int i = 1; i <= valor 5; i = i + 1)
{

}
```

En este caso los tokens que tengo son:
Linea 1:

```
PalabraReservada "For" Token1
Identificador "i = 1" Token2
PalabraReservada "To" Token3
Identificador "i <= 5"  Token4
```

Linea 2:

```
PalabraReservada "Next" Token5
```

Lo he intentado de diversas formas, pero no logro que me funcione la traducción de los tokens.

Lo que necesito ayuda, es si me pueden decir como hacer una plantilla que reciba los tokens y los cambie al nuevo lenguaje. Por favor.

Si alguien puede ayudarme muy agradecido.

Comment: Una pregunta importante para el profesor es si puedes suponer que el programa que te pasan es correcto. Esto te permitiría eliminar la necesidad de hacer muchas comprobaciones (por ejemplo podrías confiar en que los paréntesis se abren y se cierran correctamente).

Comment: Actualicé mi pregunta, no es necesario realizar validaciones. Solo transformar el código a otro lenguaje.

Comment: Mas alla de que yo siempre hice estas cosas de forma mas facil (si el primer token es un for, me voy a una funcion que ya sabe que tienen que tener los otros token y saben como parsearlo, y fin del problema), no estaria entendiendo como esperas que te ayudemos a traducir algo sobre lo cual todavia no hiciste nada.

Comment: Pues lo que tienes hasta ahora se denomina "lexer" te faltaría un "parser" que compruebe la gramática de los tokens y, a partir de plantillas, hacer la traducción al lenguaje de destino. Para lo cual deberás *poder discernir entre los diferentes tipos de tokens*.

Comment: @gbianchi, ese es el problema que tengo no logro programar la funcion para parsearlo.Si pudieras ayudarme como debe ir dicha funcion me serviria de mucho y a partir de esa tomar las ideas y programar las demas. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @aloMalbarez, las plantillas que mencionas son las que no logro programar. Lo que tengo en este momento solo es como indicas el parser, con el cual obtengo los tokens y despues los paso por automatas para saber que tipo de token es y en que posicion y linea esta ubicado. Ya al tener estos tokens y su tipo es que no logro programar la plantilla.

Comment: Tienen razón en que lo que te falta es un parser.
Al final un parser es un automata de estados, que maneja una pila.
En los libros de compiladores está descrito, como se puede transformar una gramtica en una tabla.
Esa tabla es la que junto con un algoritmo que esta descrito en los libros de compiladores, hace funcionar al parser, primero para determinar si la entrada forma parte del lenguaje descrito por la gramatica o no.
Ya se que no te piden validar la entrada, pero tampoco te vendria mal, por que de esa forma en cada transición de estado puedes generar una salida.
Una forma sencilla es tr

Comment: Hoy me indicaron que solo debo convertir la estructura de la sentencia for, while e if para ayudarnos con el curso. Intentaré nuevamente al programar las plantillas.

Comment: Si lo entendí, el analizador debe ser capáz de producir código C# desde lo que le pasas por entrada?

Comment: @NaCi gracias por tu ayuda. Puede ser a C#, Java, C++ o similar, no es obligatorio alguno en especial.

Comment: Puede ser en consola? Ya que no tengo acceso a windows forms donde estoy

Comment: Si claro, puede ser en consola. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hacer un compilador es algo relativamente complicado, yo llevo bastante tiempo intentando hacer algo personal, pero nada que no haya logrado antes. Lo que tu queires hacer es algo que requiere bastante tiempo de análisis y esta respuesta es básicamente el resumen de un libro que leí hace unos 2 años.

#### Sazonando el código <sub>(Con mucha sal)</sub>

Asumiré que ya tienes el analizador léxico completo, ese que va a tomar la entrada y a *"partirla"* en pequeñas unidades llamadas token y que utilizas la siguiente clase para almacenar un `Token`:

```
Public Class Token
  Public TType As TokenTypes
  Public Value As Object
  Public Sub New()
    ' Constructor Vacio.
  End Sub
  Public Sub New(tokType As TokenTypes, val As Object)
    TType = tokType
    Value = val
  End Sub
End Class
```

Si te fijas, `TType` es de tipo `TokenTypes`, el cual a su vez es un `Enum` definido de la siguiente manera:

```
Public Enum TokenTypes
    AddOp       ' +
    SubOp       ' -
    MulOp       ' *
    DivOp       ' /
    LesserThan  ' <
    LesserEq    ' <=
    Equals      ' = (Es el mismo que asignación)
    NotEquals   ' <>
    GreaterThan ' >
    GreaterEq   ' >=
    BoolAnd     ' And
    BooOr       ' Or
    BoolNot     ' Not
    ' Los que terminan en "Kwd" son palabras clave.
    IfKwd       ' If
    ElseIfKwd   ' ElseIf
    ElseKwd     ' Else
    ForKwd      ' For
    ToKwd       ' To
    StepKwd     ' Step
    NextKwd     ' Next [ Next i, ...  ]
    ExitKwd     ' Exit [ For, While.. ]
    DimKwd      ' Dim
    AsKwd       ' As
    IntegerKwd  ' Integer
    Ident       ' Cualquier identificador.
    Number      ' Cualquier número entero.
End Enum
```

Esta enumeración contiene los distintos tipos `Token` que tu compilador va a manejar y pues, los que *(Por ahora)* tu analizador sintactico va a utilizar, de momento no vmos a utilizar todos los tipos tokens de VB.NET, porque la lista no terminaría ahora.

La forma en la que el analizador semántico *(O sintáctico)* debe ver los tokens, seria algo como lo siguiente *(JSON-like)*:

```
"Token": { "TType": "Integer", "Value": "Integer" }
```

Posteriormente puedes guardar la linea y la columna exacta donde encontraste dicho token, pero de momento no importa.

#### La clase `Parser`

Asumo que sabes que esta etapa se encarga de validar la sintaxis de tu lenguaje *(Hasta donde yo se, pueden corregirme)* y producir una especie de Arbol de Sintaxis que posteriormente podrá ser traducido a cualquier otra cosa *(Bytecode u otro lenguaje de programación)*.

Esto sería nuestro `Parser`:

```
Public Class Parser
  ' Nuestra Lista para almacenar los tokens temporalmente.
  Private Tokens As IList(Of Token)
  Private Index As Integer
  ' La cadena en otro lenguaje de programación como resultado.
  Private Output As String

  Public Sub New(Source As IList(Of Token))
    Tokens = Source
    Index = 0
    Output = ""
  End Sub

  Private Function MatchAndEat(T As TokenTypes) As Boolean
    Dim TT = GetToken
    If Not Object.Equals(TT, Nothing) Then
      If TT.TType = T
        Index += 1 ' Avanza al siguiente token.
        Return True
      End If
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Token inesperado, se esperaba '" & T.ToString() & "'.")
    Return False
  End Function

  Private Function GetToken() As Token
    Return if(Index < Tokens.Count, Tokens(Index), Nothing)
  End Function

  Private Sub Emitir(Texto As String)
    Output = Output & Texto ' Vamos hombre...
  End Sub

  Public Function Parse() As String
     Return Output ' Todavia no vamos por aquí, asi que espera chavalito.
  End Function

End Class
```

> La función `MatchAndEat` juega un papel bastante importante en nuestro parser, ya que con el nos daremos cuenta de los tokens que necesitamos, retorna `Boolean` debido a que si el valor retornado no es `True`, debemos terminar el análisis, porque no recibimos lo que esperabamos.

Actualmente no vamos a construir ningun arbol de sintaxis, por lo que no hace falta tener una tabla de simbolos y esas cosas, solo vamos a emitir el código de un lenguaje de destino, para eso tenemos el método `Parse`.

`Parse` es el método principal del analizador y lo que hace es que compara los tokens, si encuentra un `If`, de una va y le deja el control a `ParseIf` o a otra función que se encargue de trabajar el `If`.

#### Determinando Patrones

> En esta respuesta solo voy a trabajar con lo que sería la detección de un `For` para su posterior traducción (Sin instrucciones dentro del mismo), debido a que los patrones son similares y es facil de deducir lo que sigue.

Esta es la etapa más sencilla y más compleja, determinar los patrones que coincidan con la definición de tu lenguaje, vamos a considerar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
For i = 0 To 10 Step 2
  ' Body
Next
```

Se puede entender una de dos cosas:

- La variable `i` es *inline*, es decir, propia del ciclo, o
- La variable `i` fue definida en otro lugar para su posterior uso.

Esto hay que tenerlo bastante en cuenta, para nuestro patrón vamos a asumir que los ciclos `For` van a tener su variable propia, como el código de arriba aunque de todas formas debemos manejar las expresiones aritmeticas para poder hacer algo como el `for` en C#, C o en cualquier otro lenguaje.

El algoritmo es algo más o menos como lo siguiente:

- Encontramos un `For`, lo dejamos pasar con `MatchAndEat(TokenTypes.ForKwd)`.
- Le damos el control a la función `ParseFor`:

  - Si el siguiente token no es un identificador, abortar y producir error.
  - De lo contrario, emitir el token como procede en el lenguaje de destino *(`for(int <Nombre>`)*.
  - Consumir el identificador.
  - Si el siguiente token no es un signo de asignación abortar y producir error.
  - De lo contrario emitir el signo de igual y la operación aritmetica.
  - Consumir el signo de igual y la operacion aritmetica.
  - Etc...

Lo de arriba es un poco tedioso, mejor hablemos un lenguaje que entendamos:

```
' Ahora si sabemos para que sirve Parse()
Public Function Parse() As String
  If Tokens(Index).TType = TokenTypes.For Then
    ParseFor ' Le damos el control :)
  Else
    Console.WriteLine("Token inesperado '" & Tokens(Index).TType & "', abortando.")
    Return ""
  End If
End Function
```

Eso trae consigo, otra función llamada `ParseFor()` _(Disculpen mi VB.NET, estoy bastante oxidado :P, código completo en el fiddle) :

```
  Private Sub ParseFor()
    Dim T As Token
    Dim VarName As String
    Try
      MatchAndEat(TokenTypes.ForKwd)
      Emitir("for (int ")
      T = GetToken
      If Not MatchAndEat(TokenTypes.Ident)
        Exit Sub
      End If
    ...
  End Sub
```

Ya con esto y el siguiente método `Main`, tienes para comprobar que si traduce un conjunto de tokens en lo que sería la salida "deseada":

```
Public Sub Main()
  Dim Entrada = New List(Of Token) From { _
      New Token(TokenTypes.ForKwd, Nothing) _
    , New Token(TokenTypes.Ident, "hello") _
    , New Token(TokenTypes.Equals, "=") _
    , New Token(TokenTypes.Number, "10") _
    , New Token(TokenTypes.ToKwd, "To") _
    , New Token(TokenTypes.Number, "30") _
  }
  Dim Analizador = New Parser(Entrada)
  Console.WriteLine("Producido:")
  Console.WriteLine(Analizador.Parse())
End Sub
```

El analizador semántico/sintáctico que hicimos *(Malo, pero bueno)* puede traducir la expresión:

```
For i = 0 To 10 Step 1
Next
```

A:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
}
```

Pero esto es porque no hemos realizado los *tweaks* correspondientes para hacer que convierta más expresiones.

El siguiente paso luego de leer esta respuesta, es leerse cualquier libro práctico que trate sobre la construcción de compiladores, así se gana una idea más amplia y mucho más entendible para desarrollar compiladores.

---

Referencias y otras cosas:

- [Practical Interpreter Construction](https://leanpub.com/pic)
- [Un Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0xMYhJ)

Comment: sin duda alguna, eres el legendario Cloruro de Sodio, conocido también como el Salero de SOes :D

Comment: Vine buscando  bronce y encontré oro. Gracias @NaCI tu respuesta es magistral, aprendí tanto en pocas lineas. Muy agradecido por la ayuda.

Comment: En pocas líneas? Jajaja, duré poco más de 4 horas haciendo eso :P, pero fue bien divertido

Comment: Bueno en pocas lineas comparado con las miles de lineas de un libro XD Gracias por dedicar tu tiempo a mi pregunta. Tu respuesta es de muchísima ayuda, y se que muchas personas que tengan la misma inquietud que yo, les será valiosa tu respuesta.

Comment: Odio las cartas, pero esta se ve buena la leere

Comment: @NaCl el libro que mencionas ya no esta disponible para su compra?

Comment: @Crack81 Al parecer ya no, pero creo tener una copia guardada en mi google drive :)